# How to use Google People API in Chrome extension to get my contacts names, emails, phone numbers and organizations

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-people-api

I am new to Chrome extensions and People API. I am trying to create an extension with JavaScript so that I can list my contacts.

I get a 401 error:

> error: {code: 401, data: undefined, message: "Request is missing required authentication credent…ogle.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."}
> message: "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity
>
> GET https://content-people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?requestMask.includeField=person.phone_numbers%2Cperson.organizations%2Cperson.email_addresses%2Cperson.names&pageSize=100&key=AIzaSyBAoWON7yo4fJimEFDk3VIonx3S1YjyqeQ 401

manifest.json:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"key":"key..............",
"oauth2": {
  "client_id": "..........apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "scopes": [
    "profile email",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/directory.readonly" ,
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.addresses.read", 
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read", 
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.emails.read", 
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read", 
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.organization.read" ,
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read" ,
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" ,
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read"
  ]
},
"name": "GmailM",
"version": "0.1",
"description":"simple email extension",
"persistent": false,
content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 
 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
"permissions": 
 ["identity","https://apis.google.com/js/api.js", 
 "https://accounts.google.com/*",  
"https://www.googleapis.com/*"],
"browser_action":{
  "default_title":"timezone finder"
  
},
"background": {
  "scripts": [
      "./background.js"
 ]
 },
}
```

test.js:

```js
var theParent = document.querySelector("#ParentId");

if (theParent) {   
     theParent.addEventListener("click",callApi,false);
}
function callApi(e) {
    if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
        var clickedItem = e.target.id;

        if (clickedItem === "contacts") {
            console.log(clickedItem+ " ppl api ");
            authClick();
        }
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
}

function authClick() {
    var CLIENT_ID = '....';
    var SCOPES = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts", 
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly", 
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/directory.readonly", 
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.addresses.read", 
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read", 
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.emails.read", 
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read", 
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.organization.read", 
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read", 
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", 
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",         
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read"
    ];
    gapi.auth.authorize({ 
        client_id: CLIENT_ID, 
        scope: SCOPES, 
        immediate: false 
    }, authResult);
    return false;
}

function authResult(_Result) {
    var _Div = document.getElementById('divauthresult');
    if (_Result && !_Result.error) {
        _Div.style.display = 'none';
        loadPeopleApi();
        console.log("yes");
    } else {
        // Auth Error, allowing the user to initiate authorization by
        _Div.innerText = ':( Authtentication Error : ' + _Result.error;
        console.log("no");
    }
}

function loadPeopleApi() { 
    gapi.client.setApiKey("AIzaSyBAoWON7yo4fJimEFDk3VIonx3S1YjyqeQ");         
    gapi.client.load('https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest', 'v1', showContacts);
}

function showContacts() { 
    var request = gapi.client.people.people.connections.list({
        
        'resourceName': 'people/me',
        'pageSize': 100,
        'requestMask.includeField': 'person.phone_numbers,person.organizations,person.email_addresses,person.names'
    });

    request.execute(function(resp) {
        var connections = resp.connections;
        console.log("hii");
        console.log(resp);

        if (connections.length > 0) {
            var _Html = "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Company</th><th>Phone</th></tr>";
            var _EmptyCell = "<td> - </td>";

            for (i = 0; i < connections.length; i++) {
                var person = connections[i];
                _Html += "<tr>";

                if (person.names && person.names.length > 0)
                    _Html += "<td>" + person.names[0].displayName + "</td>";
                else
                    _Html += _EmptyCell;

                if (person.emailAddresses && person.emailAddresses.length > 0)
                    _Html += "<td>" + person.emailAddresses[0].value + "</td>";
                else
                    _Html += _EmptyCell;

                if (person.organizations && person.organizations.length > 0)
                    _Html += "<td>" + person.organizations[0].name + "</td>";
                else
                    _Html += _EmptyCell;

                if (person.phoneNumbers && person.phoneNumbers.length > 0)
                    _Html += "<td>" + 
              person.phoneNumbers[0].value + "</td>";
                else
                    _Html += _EmptyCell;

                _Html += "</tr>";
            }
            divtableresult.innerHTML = "Contacts found : 
            <br>" + _Html;
        } else {
            divtableresult.innerHTML = "";
            divauthresult.innerText = "No Contacts 
           found!";
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Browser Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/js)? The problem returned by the API is clearly about the token, but my understanding of chrome extensions is not so good.

Answer (score 0):

I have been tackling this problem just recently myself. How, I solved it was by doing the follow

**Steps**

1. Use OAuth2 to get access token
2. Use access token to get **userinfo** GET -
   `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=${accessToken}`
3. Get the google **id** from the **userinfo** object.
4. Specify your **personFields**. You read more about personFields
   [here](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get). *(e.g
   coverPhotos,emailAddresses,genders,locales,occupations)* Make sure
   you have and **api key** you can watch this video on how to get an
   api key for Google People API. [Watch Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iM12nF0tBuM).
5. So you need four things **Access Token**, **GoogleId**, **Api Key** and
   **personFields**.
6. Finally GET - `https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/${googleId}?alt=json&personFields=${personFields}&key=${apiKey}&access_token=${accessToken}`